# Call to undefined method Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

> Call to undefined method Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::_config()
>   in
>   cakephp3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Datasource/ConnectionManager.php
>   on line 80

After I put my DB details whle installation of Cakephp 3.X on cPanel (on localhost it works fine) it gives this error. Help

Comment: It seems to be a problem with php version 5.4.4x. There are several bugs reported about it, the closest description to my problem is [this one](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63394). I tried several things to fix it, even removing xcache as the bug comments says, but nothing worked. I guess you will have to upgrade php.

Answer (score 0):

You try change the name of app.default.php to app.php, if you do, then paste your app.php to see other problems.

Comment: Problem remains after doing this. Actually its working fine on localhost, on cPanel its giving this error. Also for the first run it shows that cake's green page and when i refresh it, it show these errors.

Comment: 'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            ,
            'username' => 'my_app',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'database' => 'my_app',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,

     
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

   
        ],